# Simplifying $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

$$\text{I need to prove the following lemma : }\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}  = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\text{We know that }\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} $$$$\text{So, }\zeta'(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{ds}.\frac{1}{n^s} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ln(n)}{n^s}$$

This gives : $$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}  = -\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ln(n)}{n^s}} $$

How do I proceed ? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to show that $\log n = \sum_{d | n } \Lambda(d)$. So by [Mobius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) it follows that $\Lambda(n) = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \log(n/d)$. We know that $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$ and $$\zeta'(s) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^s}$$, so by [Dirchlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) we have $$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \log(n/d) \frac1{n^s} = -\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$$

Comment: Why are we using Dirichlet convolution instead of normal multiplication ?

Comment: It is indeed normal multiplication of two series. The property of this convolution is that $\sum_{n} \frac{a(n)}{n^s} \dot \sum_{n} \frac{b(n)}{n^s}=   \sum_{n} \frac{a * b}{n^{s}}= \sum_{n} \sum_{d|n}a(d)b(n/d) n^{-s}$ where $*$ is the convolution .

Comment: It is a good exercise to prove the equality $$\sum_{n} \frac{a(n)}{n^s} \dot \sum_{n} \frac{b(n)}{n^s}=    \sum_{n} \sum_{d|n}a(d)b(n/d) n^{-s}$$ for any general arithmetic functions $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac{d}{ds}\ln\zeta(s)=-\sum_p\frac d{ds}\ln(1-p^{-s}).$$